# windows 10 bootcamp wireless display adapter macbook pro 2017

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

Has anyone got a stable setup for miracast to a microsoft wireless display adapter from a 13" macbook pro 2017?

Previous macbooks (air & pro) connect without issue.  The latest model will connect, but it is very intermittent, mostly can't see the adapter and mostly fails to connect when it can see it.

windows 10 is version 1709 and fully up to date.  macbook firmware and drivers are fully up to date and the microsoft wireless display adapter has latest firmware (V.2.0.8372).

Also - running the command:

```
netsh wlan show drivers
```

Shows:

```
Wireless Display Supported: Yes (Graphics Driver: Yes, Wi-Fi Driver: Yes)
```

Update: still the same situation in windows 10 version 1803 - wireless display adapter firmware version unchanged

Answer (score 1):

This occurred for me once I updated the graphics driver from the Apple update.  It was working fine with a fresh install until that update was applied (May 2018).  I reloaded Windows in Bootcamp again and got the same result.